# Yum update fails after running out of memory

Tags: yum

I ran out of memory when trying yum update.  Increased memory, however the previous yum update fail when it ran out of memory and no I cannot complete the update.

Now when I run yum update I get:

```
Error: Package: coreutils-libs-8.4-31.el6_5.2.x86_64 (@updates)
           Requires: coreutils = 8.4-31.el6_5.2
           Removing: coreutils-8.4-31.el6_5.2.x86_64 (@updates)
               coreutils = 8.4-31.el6_5.2
           Updated By: coreutils-8.4-37.el6.x86_64 (base)
               coreutils = 8.4-37.el6
Error: Package: abrt-addon-ccpp-2.0.8-21.el6.centos.x86_64 (@base)
           Requires: abrt = 2.0.8-21.el6.centos
           Removing: abrt-2.0.8-21.el6.centos.x86_64 (@base)
               abrt = 2.0.8-21.el6.centos
           Updated By: abrt-2.0.8-26.el6.centos.x86_64 (base)
               abrt = 2.0.8-26.el6.centos
Error: Package: abrt-addon-python-2.0.8-21.el6.centos.x86_64 (@base)
           Requires: abrt = 2.0.8-21.el6.centos
           Removing: abrt-2.0.8-21.el6.centos.x86_64 (@base)
               abrt = 2.0.8-21.el6.centos
           Updated By: abrt-2.0.8-26.el6.centos.x86_64 (base)
               abrt = 2.0.8-26.el6.centos
Error: Package: abrt-addon-kerneloops-2.0.8-21.el6.centos.x86_64 (@base)
           Requires: abrt = 2.0.8-21.el6.centos
           Removing: abrt-2.0.8-21.el6.centos.x86_64 (@base)
               abrt = 2.0.8-21.el6.centos
           Updated By: abrt-2.0.8-26.el6.centos.x86_64 (base)
               abrt = 2.0.8-26.el6.centos
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
```

rpm -q coreutils-libs abrt-addon-ccpp abrt-addon-python abrt-addon-kerneloops:

```
coreutils-libs-8.4-37.el6.x86_64
coreutils-libs-8.4-31.el6_5.2.x86_64
abrt-addon-ccpp-2.0.8-21.el6.centos.x86_64
abrt-addon-ccpp-2.0.8-26.el6.centos.x86_64
abrt-addon-python-2.0.8-26.el6.centos.x86_64
abrt-addon-python-2.0.8-21.el6.centos.x86_64
abrt-addon-kerneloops-2.0.8-26.el6.centos.x86_64
abrt-addon-kerneloops-2.0.8-21.el6.centos.x86_64
```

Comment: What repositories do you have enabled? What are the baseurls for them? What does `rpm -q coreutils-libs abrt-addon-ccpp abrt-addon-python abrt-addon-kerneloops` output? Does running `yum clean all && yum makecache` change the output from `yum update`?

Comment: See edit for output of rpm -q coreutils-libs abrt-addon-ccpp abrt-addon-python abrt-addon-kerneloops.  yum clean all yum makecache yum updates same problem.

Comment: What does `yum-complete-transaction` output? If it indicates it had work to do does that change that `rpm -q` output or the output from `yum update`?

Comment: yum-complete-transaction: No unfinished transactions left.

Comment: What does `rpm -q abrt coreutils` say? If it lists `abrt-2.0.8-26.el6.centos.x86_64` and `coreutils-8.4-37.el6.x86_64` then you could try manually removing the older `coreutils-libs`, `abrt-addon-ccpp`, `abrt-addon-python`, and `abrt-addon-kerneloops` packages and seeing if that fixes the problem.

Comment: rpm -q abrt coreutils:
abrt-2.0.8-21.el6.centos.x86_64
coreutils-8.4-31.el6_5.2.x86_64

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68430/discussion-between-etan-reisner-and-lostintranslation).

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a repository mismatch.

you didn't describe what version of your Linux distribution you are using (CentOS, Scientific Linux or a Redhat Enterprise Linux)

yum repolist to get active repositories, so you can see which are activated and to provide us for more information.

`yum-complete-transaction` is a good command to resume cancelled yum install or yum updates.

See more @ http://linux.die.net/man/8/yum-complete-transaction

You can try and disable all repositories and enable them one by one.

I would recommend you should enable only the one specific for your release.

Please provide us with more information.

1. Linux release and distribution
2. output of yum repolist